# CefSharp : Scroll the page up based on the position of the Textbox on the page (CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser)

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I want to do something like this because of the problem that the on-screen keyboard comes in front of the inputs when I click on the textbox and prevents the entries from being seen, is it possible?

1) When any textbox is clicked on the page, I want to get the position information of that textbox and make the calculation according to the size of the on-screen keyboard and scroll the page up if necessary. In summary, I would like to manually move the textbox above the keyboard.

2) Also, if we can get Textbox information, can we open the keyboard or numpad according to whether it is numeric or alphanumeric?

Note 1: CEF Version: v75.1.143.

Note 2: Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC (version:1809, OS Build: 17763.864).

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You might be able to hack something together using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRenderProcessMessageHandler_OnFocusedNodeChanged.htm you'll need to enable by setting http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_FocusedNodeChangedEnabled.htm before any call to `Cef.Initialzie`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your guidance and assistance, @amaitland. Can you share a sample code/link on how to use this method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an example in the project source, I have no example that meets your exact requirements. You'd probably have to execute some JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView